# I can't change the color of the place I choose randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to paint a random place black every 1 second, but what I did not succeed,my code is long I did not share here https://codepen.io/sinanelms/pen/MqdNNY?editors=0010 I'd be happy to help you.when I do it like this, it can't paint anywhere.

```
for (var county in paths) {

        var obj = r.path(paths[county].path);
      //random selected
    function random(){

                var ran=Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);

                if(obj.id==ran){obj.animate({fill: '#000'}, 200);   } 
              }

              setInterval(function(){random();}, 1000);
    //random end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a really bad organized code. I didn't understand anything untill edit myself.(still didn't get it.)
 But i wrote something that does what you want.

- Add this var to somewhere outside of for loop in your code 
  `var allobjs = [];`

  *Like

  var allobjs = [], w = 1000, h=500;*
- I rewrite your rand function

  ```
  function random(){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allobjs.length - 1) ) + 1;
      if (allobjs[random].id != 'blank'){
          allobjs[random].animate({fill: '#000'}, 200);
      } 
  }
  setInterval(function(){random();}, 1000);
  ```

**Add this after the $(window).resize, not inside. Do not forget to delete your own function and setInterval**

- Add this code to for loop

  `var obj = r.path(paths[county].path);`

*Like

    for (var county in paths) {

        var obj = r.path(paths[county].path);*

Reload the page and you're good to go
If you want edited version of your code (I edit only tabs and line breaks):
https://codepen.io/truetiem/pen/rqaOOV

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I want a city to delete every previous choice in every random selection. Thank you very much help me :)

Comment: So, you can store previous city in a variable, and then delete this previous city.
'var prevcity = null;'
And in the random function just add;
if (prevcity != null){prevcity.animate..... etc}

Comment: i couldn't :( I don't know what you're saying.I have very little knowledge of JavaScript. my goal is to keep it selected in the ID I sent from Python Flask After making random selections here.